# Manufacturer and wireless cards OUI

Tags: mac-address

Some devices have an OUI that isn't the one belonging to the manufacturer of the device. For example, my Sony mobile phone has a MAC address which belongs to Airgo Networks.

Is there a database where I can find the manufacturer (Sony) that uses a wireless card with an OUI (Airgo Newtorks) that doesn't belong to the manufacturer?

Comment: You can find a list of [all OUI assignments here](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf).

Comment: @user2540549 As **Ron_Maupin** explained, the vendor might use components from another vendor. In my opinion, this should be expected when it comes to (assembled) devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know Airgo Networks didn't manufacture the card in the Sony device? Device manufacturers use parts from other manufacturers all the time, especially if they don't make network chipsets. Sony, itself, may not even have a registered OUI. Many PCs have MAC addresses which are not from the PC manufacturer, but from the manufacturer of the network chipset. This is not unusual, and the OUI does belong to the manufacturer (of the chipset).

There are Internet sites which maintain OUI databases, but there is no database to relate the device manufacturer to a particular network chipset since each device manufacturer is free to use the lowest bid or change suppliers or contracts at any given time. Many different device manufacturers can, and do, use network chipsets from the same network chipset manufacturer, so the same OUI may be used by disparate device manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

None that I'm aware of.  It would be difficult, because a computer manufacturer could change parts (use a different card manufacturer) at any time.

Comment: And the same card would be used in many different devices made by many different companies.